# How can I t-test rates of conversion?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have two ad campaigns, each with 5000 impressions served and industry-comparable conversion rates.  In R, this looks like

```
    imps_1 <- rpois(5000, 1000)
    imps_2 <- rpois(5000, 1200)
    conv_1 <- rbinom(5000, 100, 0.05)
    conv_2 <- rbinom(5000, 200, 0.07)
    cr_1 <- sum(conv_1)/sum(imps_1)
    cr_2 <- sum(conv_2)/sum(imps_2)
  cr_1
[1] 0.005005101
  cr_2
[1] 0.01165382
```

My questions are:

1. How do I test the significance of cr_1 and cr_2, and
2. How do I run a t-test on whether these two rates are the same?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a relationship between the "imps" and "conv" variables?  As you have defined it you have found the ratio if an independent binomial random variable with n = 100 and 200 respectively and an independent Poisson random variable with rate parameter 1000 and 1200 respectively.

Comment: there is typically a 0.5% conversion rate (probability of success) for each impression...how should I modify?

Comment: It sounds like you need to make your number trials for your binomial random variable to be equal to the result of your number of impressions. That would require this change: `conv_1 <- rbinom(5000, imps_1, 0.05)`. I'm not sure what you mean by an impression but that would equate to 5000 samples, where each sample is a binomial draw from something like 1000 trials.

Comment: You may also want to set the random seed (`set.seed(1)`) for reproducibility.